# Synchronizing windows clock using GPS

Tags: python, windows, api, gps

We have two systems with built in GPS today I spent a little time, and I wrote some code to get the coordinate. My question is How can I get the GPS time and update the system clock under Windows 7 64bit?

Comment: This is only partially a Python question.  It's more of a Windows 64 question on which of the API calls changes the clock.  Please update your tags.

Comment: How you get the GPS coordinates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GPS time you may read from NMEA sentences; the same way like coords.

Clock update in WinAPI:

```
BOOL SetSystemTime(CONST SYSTEMTIME *lpSystemTime);
```

under pywin32:

```
win32api.SetSystemTime
```

Answer (score 1):

What library are you using for processing the GPS data? If you're using gpsd, I'd look to do the following:-

> import gps
>
> session - gps.gps()
>   time = session.utc, session.fix.time

You could then use the information provided by Skippy to update the system clock using the variable 'time'

Comment: Unfortunately  gpsd  doesn't support windows.